# Custom List Result with Content Type=SPSPeople in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, people-search

Is it possible to get Custom List Result with `Content Type=SPSPeople` and display:

1. Only the Custom List Result
2. Merge Custom List Result and People Search result Using SharePoint Online

I tried the approach suggested in:

[Workaround to show Contact items in People Search](https://www.techmikael.com/2014/04/workaround-to-show-contact-items-in.html).

& the Responses in 
[Mix two Result Sources in Search Results Web Part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95403/mix-two-result-sources-in-search-results-web-part)

But not able to proceed. 
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a query rule to include people results to everything search results within your search site.

And here is the link for your reference:

[Adding People to Everything Search Results](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-adding-people-to.html)

Besides, limit the search scope in the custom list in the search result web part as shown below:

[image]